# pthreads / C : using a flag to gracefully terminate other threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Is it safe (and a good practice) to use a flag which is **written by only one thread** and only read by other threads to gracefully terminate threads?

Consider the following code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int run;
static pthread_t t1, t2;

static void *threadFunc(void *context)
{
    puts("thread starting");

    init();

    while(run)
    {
        do_stuff();
    }

    clean_up();

    puts("thread exiting");

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    puts("program starting");
    run = 1;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, threadFunc, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, threadFunc, NULL);

    do_some_stuff();

    run = 0;

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    puts("program exiting");
    return 0;
}
```

The variable "run" is used to tell threads t1 and t2 to terminate. Is that fine or I should use a mutex / memory barriers? And why?
I don't care if it takes a couple more loop cycles before the threads exit, but I don't want them to run forever.
I don't want to use pthread_cancel() as I want the threads to quit only after they complete a cycle of their main loop.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

The safest approach is to make `run` atomic. Modern C does support atomic types.

Comment: OK but is it enough?

Comment: It should be. Typical `atomic` types are defined to be safe for concurrent modification and access and typically do guarantee that changes will be seen by other threads "soon".

Comment: is sigatomic_t good enough or I must use C11 stdatomic?

Comment: sigatomic_t is for signals and not meant for multithreading

Comment: ok so just change the type of run from int to atomic_int would do it?

Comment: My toolchain appears to be too old to have stdatomic.h. What's the next best solution? Mutex? Or is there something that would be as simple as changing the type of variable run to something else? Can sync_synchronize be of any help here? Any less portable GCC builtin?

Answer (score 2):

You need a mutex to protect the shared variable because that's what the pthreads standard says. You can't assume that the worst way it will fail is taking "a couple more loop cycles before the threads exit".

It can crash. It can fail to ever stop. Anything can happen.

If your platform supports some kind of atomic type or atomic operations, you can use that.

Some people think using `volatile` is acceptable *only* for a "shutdown" flag. Be aware that this is very platform-specific and may or may not work for you. I don't consider it acceptable on platforms that have better options, that is, on all modern platforms.

Comment: so acquire the mutex on every read, on every cycle, and when writing as well?

Comment: @user1472946 Yes. If you're going to use a mutex, that's how you have to do it. Writes should be rare and cycles should be fairly far apart too. Alternatively, every modern platform has some kind of atomic operation or atomic type that will avoid the extra locks/unlocks. (Uncontended mutexes are nearly free anyway,)

Comment: since there is only one thread writing and two reading, would it be more efficient to use a read-write lock instead of a mutex?

Comment: @user1472946 Probably not. The lock is only held for a split second, so there's virtually no contention to minimize. The extra overhead of the read/write lock won't yield any benefit.

Comment: Worth adding volatile tells the compiler that the memory location referred to by the variable may be changed outside of the programs control. This means that the compiler cannot make assumptions about the value of the memory address and potentially optimize the read away. So volatile helps a bit. What is also required (assuming the datatype is smaller than word size)  is a data memory barrier. This will ensure core specific caches will see the read from the other CPU. Both atomics and mutexes make sure that this happens.

Comment: so on a single core CPU volatile would be fine, but it's not very portable as it's not enough on multicore?